# How can I compute the angular velocity of a triangle formed by three particles knowing their instantaneous positions and velocities?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, geometry, rotational-kinematics, angular-velocity

I have a set of trajectories of three particles and their instantaneous velocities. I would like to compute the 3 components of the angular velocity pseudovector of the fictive triangle formed by these three particles. How can I proceed for that?

Comment: Part of my wants to say "use the definition," but I assume you've tried that. Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the particle locations be $\{\mathbf{r}_1(t),\mathbf{r}_2(t),\mathbf{r}_3(t)\}$. Without loss of generality, assume $\mathbf{r}_1(t)=\mathbf{0}.$ Then the unit normal $\widehat{\mathbf{n}}(t)$ to the triangle becomes
$$\widehat{\mathbf{n}}=\frac{\mathbf{r}_2\times\mathbf{r}_3}{|\mathbf{r}_2\times\mathbf{r}_3|}$$
and the angular velocity of $\widehat{\mathbf{n}}$ becomes
$$\boldsymbol{\omega}=\widehat{\mathbf{n}}\times\dot{\widehat{\mathbf{n}}}.$$
Written in component form with $$\mathbf{r}_k(t)=\pmatrix{x_k(t)\\y_k(t)\\z_k(t)},$$
this becomes
$$\boldsymbol{\omega}(t)=\left(\frac{\left[x_2^2 \left(-\dot{y_3}\right) z_3+x_2 \dot{z_3} \left(x_2 y_3-x_3 y_2\right)+x_3 x_2 \dot{y_3} z_2-\dot{x_3} x_2 y_3
   z_2+x_3 x_2 \dot{y_2} z_3+\dot{x_3} x_2 y_2 z_3+x_3 \dot{z_2} \left(x_3 y_2-x_2 y_3\right)-x_3^2 \dot{y_2} z_2+\dot{x_2} x_3 y_3
   z_2-\dot{x_2} x_3 y_2 z_3\right]}{\left(x_3 y_2-x_2 y_3\right){}^2+\left(x_3 z_2-x_2 z_3\right){}^2+\left(y_3 z_2-y_2
   z_3\right){}^2},\frac{\left[\dot{x_3} y_2^2 z_3+y_2 \dot{z_3} \left(x_2 y_3-x_3 y_2\right)+x_3 \dot{y_3} y_2 z_2-\dot{x_3} y_3 y_2
   z_2-x_2 \dot{y_3} y_2 z_3-\dot{x_2} y_3 y_2 z_3+y_3 \dot{z_2} \left(x_3 y_2-x_2 y_3\right)+\dot{x_2} y_3^2 z_2-x_3 \dot{y_2} y_3
   z_2+x_2 \dot{y_2} y_3 z_3\right]}{\left(x_3 y_2-x_2 y_3\right){}^2+\left(x_3 z_2-x_2 z_3\right){}^2+\left(y_3 z_2-y_2
   z_3\right){}^2},\frac{\left[-\dot{x_3} y_3 z_2^2+\dot{z_3} z_2 \left(x_2 y_3-x_3 y_2\right)-x_3 \dot{y_2} z_3 z_2+\dot{x_3} y_2 z_3
   z_2+\dot{x_2} y_3 z_3 z_2+\dot{y_3} z_2 \left(x_3 z_2-x_2 z_3\right)+x_2 \dot{y_2} z_3^2-\dot{x_2} y_2 z_3^2+x_3 y_2 \dot{z_2}
   z_3-x_2 y_3 \dot{z_2} z_3\right]}{\left(x_3 y_2-x_2 y_3\right){}^2+\left(x_3 z_2-x_2 z_3\right){}^2+\left(y_3 z_2-y_2
   z_3\right){}^2}\right).$$

Naturally, if you're doing this on a computer with discrete time-step $\Delta t$, instead of the long expression above, it should be easier to use
$$\boldsymbol{\omega}(t)=\widehat{\mathbf{n}}(t)\times\frac{\widehat{\mathbf{n}}(t)-\widehat{\mathbf{n}}(t-\Delta t)}{\Delta t}.$$

Comment: Thanks so much DumpsterDoofus for your answer. I think that it is what I am looking for. I tried to apply it for 2 particles and I got the correct formula!

Comment: @Strömungsmechanik: I assume you used $\boldsymbol{\omega}(t)=\widehat{\mathbf{n}}(t)\times\frac{\widehat{\mathbf{n}}(t)-\widehat{\mathbf{n}}(t-\Delta t)}{\Delta t}$ right?

Comment: In fact the first formula you wrote is indeed great, I mean the definition of the rotation vector. I can derive now the desired information from it since I have all the position and velocities of my three particles at every time. The use of the last formula is frustrating since it is difficult to access to two successive times from my database of particles. Thanks again for your powerful help!

Comment: I don't understand. Why are we interested in the angular velocity of $\hat{n}$? If it is spinning perpendicular to its plane, won't $\hat{n}$ be zero, while there is nonzero angular velocity?

Answer (score 0):

With a change of coordinates, you can move to the reference frame of the centre of mass.

$$ \hat x_i(t) = x_i(t) - \frac{1}{3}\sum_j ^3 x_j (t) $$

And the same for $y$ and $z$. From there, you can compute the angle of one of the vertex. In 2D, for simplicty:

$$ \hat\theta_i = \arctan \frac{\hat y_i}{\hat x_i}$$

For 3D you need to do a bit more geometry.

Answer (score 0):

Compute the center of mass and velocity of center of mass at each frame

$$ \vec{r}_C = \frac{1}{3} \left( \vec{r}_1  + \vec{r}_2 + \vec{r}_3 \right) $$
$$ \vec{v}_C = \frac{1}{3} \left( \vec{v}_1  + \vec{v}_2 + \vec{v}_3 \right) $$

Then you have 9 equations for 3 unknowns which you solve with a least squares method.

$$ \begin{pmatrix} \vec{v}_1 \\ \vec{v}_2  \\ \vec{v}_3  \end{pmatrix}  = 
\begin{pmatrix} \vec{v}_C \\ \vec{v}_C  \\ \vec{v}_C  \end{pmatrix}
+ \begin{bmatrix} (\vec{r}_C - \vec{r}_1)\times \\ (\vec{r}_C - \vec{r}_2)\times
\\ (\vec{r}_C - \vec{r}_3)\times \end{bmatrix} \vec{\omega} $$

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 
0 & z_1 -z_C & y_C-y_1 \\ 
z_C-z_1 & 0 & x_1-x_C \\
y_1-y_C & x_C - x_1 & 0 \\
0 & z_2 -z_C & y_C-y_2 \\ 
z_C-z_2 & 0 & x_2-x_C \\
y_2-y_C & x_C - x_2 & 0 \\
0 & z_3 -z_C & y_C-y_3 \\ 
z_C-z_3 & 0 & x_3-x_C \\
y_3-y_C & x_C - x_3 & 0 
\end{bmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix} \omega_x \\ \omega_y \\ \omega_z \end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix} 
vx_1 - vx_C \\vy_1 - vy_C\\vz_1 - vz_C \\
vx_2 - vx_C \\vy_2 - vy_C\\vz_2 - vz_C \\
vx_3 - vx_C \\vy_3 - vy_C\\vz_3 - vz_C 
\end{pmatrix} $$

If stated as $A \omega = b$ then $$\boxed{\omega = (A^\top A)^{-1} (A^\top b)}$$ is the last squares solution.